# Problem with multirow, tabularx and ltablex

Tags: tables, tabularx, multirow, multicolumn, ltablex

I am trying to make a table in LaTeX but I am failing. I have tried loads of things but I don't get a result. Despite using `tabularx`, words do not fit the columns.

```
 \documentclass[]{article}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[english, spanish, es-noshorthands]{babel}
  \title{}
  \author{}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage{adjustbox}
   \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{ltablex}
  \newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
    \begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{1.22\linewidth}{|Y|Y|Y|Y|c|Y|Y|}
\hline
\multicolumn{7}{ |c| }{Tema 6. Álgebra.} \\  \hline
\endhead
Bloques & Contenidos & Criterios de evaluación& Estándares&Instrumentos & Valor máx. estándar& Competencias\\ \hline
\multirow{2}{2cm}{1. Procesos, métodos y actitudes en matemáticas.}& \multirow{2}{2cm}{Estrategias y
    procedimientos
    puestos en
    práctica: uso
    del lenguaje
    apropiado
    (gráfico,
    numérico,
    algebraico,
    etc.),
    reformulación
    del problema,
    resolver
    subproblemas,
    recuento
    exhaustivo,
    empezar por
    casos
    particulares
    sencillos,
    buscar
    regularidades y
    leyes, etc.
    Planteamiento
    de
    investigaciones
    matemáticas
    escolares en
    contextos
    numéricos,
    geométricos y
    funcionales.
    Confianza en
    las propias
    capacidades
    para
    desarrollar
    actitudes
    adecuadas y
    afrontar las
    dificultades
    propias del
    trabajo
    científico.
    Utilización de
    medios
    tecnológicos
    en el proceso
    de
    aprendizaje}& 5.Desarrollar
procesos de
matematización
en contextos de
la realidad
cotidiana
(numéricos,
geométricos y
funcionales) a
partir de la
identificación de
problemas en
situaciones
problemáticas de
la realidad.& 1.Realiza
simulaciones y
predicciones, en
el contexto real,
para valorar la
adecuación y
las limitaciones
de los modelos,
proponiendo
mejoras que
aumenten su
eficacia.&Prueba
escrita:50
Trabajos:50 &0.176 & AA
CMCT\\ \cline{3-7}
&&7.Emplear las
herramientas
tecnológicas
adecuadas, de
forma autónoma,
realizando
cálculos
numéricos o
algebraicos,
haciendo
representaciones
gráficas,
recreando
situaciones
matemáticas
mediante
simulaciones o
analizando con
sentido crítico
situaciones
diversas que
ayuden a la
comprensión de
conceptos
matemáticos o a
la resolución de
problemas.&1.Selecciona
herramientas
tecnológicas
adecuadas y las
utiliza para la
realización de
cálculos
numéricos y
algebraicos
cuando la
dificultad de los
mismos impide o
no aconseja
hacerlos
manualmente.&Trabajos:100&0.176&CDIG
CMCT\\ \hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have a table with seven columns, one of which (the 5th) is quite a bit wider than the other six. You have a substantial amount of text in column 2, while columns 1, 5, 6, and 7 are all nearly empty. Why are you even trying to shoe-horn all this disparate material into a single table?

Comment: even in landscape mode you have to much text in second column. see, if transform columns into rows, and rows into column can help you.

Answer (score 3):

the tabular layout is not helping, I'd do.

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[english, spanish, es-noshorthands]{babel}
  \title{}
  \author{}

    \begin{document}



\section*{Tema 6. Álgebra.} 

\begin{description}

\item[Bloques]
1. Procesos, métodos y actitudes en matemáticas.
\item[Contenidos]
Estrategias y
    procedimientos
    puestos en
    práctica: uso
    del lenguaje
    apropiado
    (gráfico,
    numérico,
    algebraico,
    etc.),
    reformulación
    del problema,
    resolver
    subproblemas,
    recuento
    exhaustivo,
    empezar por
    casos
    particulares
    sencillos,
    buscar
    regularidades y
    leyes, etc.
    Planteamiento
    de
    investigaciones
    matemáticas
    escolares en
    contextos
    numéricos,
    geométricos y
    funcionales.
    Confianza en
    las propias
    capacidades
    para
    desarrollar
    actitudes
    adecuadas y
    afrontar las
    dificultades
    propias del
    trabajo
    científico.
    Utilización de
    medios
    tecnológicos
    en el proceso
    de
    aprendizaje
\item[Criterios de evaluación]
 5.Desarrollar
procesos de
matematización
en contextos de
la realidad
cotidiana
(numéricos,
geométricos y
funcionales) a
partir de la
identificación de
problemas en
situaciones
problemáticas de
la realidad.
\item[Estándares]
 1.Realiza
simulaciones y
predicciones, en
el contexto real,
para valorar la
adecuación y
las limitaciones
de los modelos,
proponiendo
mejoras que
aumenten su
eficacia.
\item[Instrumentos]
Prueba
escrita:50
Trabajos:50 
\item[Valor máx. estándar]
0.176
\item[Competencias]
AA CMCT
\end{description}
\begin{description}

\item[Bloques]
?
\item[Contenidos]
?
\item[Criterios de evaluación]
7.Emplear las
herramientas
tecnológicas
adecuadas, de
forma autónoma,
realizando
cálculos
numéricos o
algebraicos,
haciendo
representaciones
gráficas,
recreando
situaciones
matemáticas
mediante
simulaciones o
analizando con
sentido crítico
situaciones
diversas que
ayuden a la
comprensión de
conceptos
matemáticos o a
la resolución de
problemas.
\item[Criterios de evaluación]
1.Selecciona
herramientas
tecnológicas
adecuadas y las
utiliza para la
realización de
cálculos
numéricos y
algebraicos
cuando la
dificultad de los
mismos impide o
no aconseja
hacerlos
manualmente.
\item[Estándares]
Trabajos:100
\item[Valor máx. estándar]
0.176
\item[Competencias]
CDIG CMCT
\end{description}

\end{document}
```